# Website for making class diagrams?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

Do any web 2.0 like websites exist for prototyping object oriented class diagrams?

Comment: Are you interested in just improving your object oriented design skills? Or are you looking specifically for tools for prototyping?

Comment: Just a tool. Good point, renamed title.

Comment: I've marked a correct answer. However I would appreciate other websites if any exist! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://yuml.me/